# MySQL rows to a PHP class array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a class that i made, `class art` in PHP. I want to copy data from a MySQL table to an array of `class art` objects (array size varies depending on the tables number of rows).  The table containing the data has the same structure as my `class art`.

SHORT VERSION: Is it possible to create an array of `art` objects in PHP and how do I do that?

Here's the class that I have:

```
<?php

class art {
    var $title='';
    var $body='';
    var $category='';
    var $date='';

    function does_whatever() { }
}
?>
```

Here's the MySQL and code that should add each row of data as an 'art' object to an array:

```
    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "blog");
    $query = "select * from article";
    if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) 
    {
     while ($obj = $result->fetch_object())
        { //create the array of art type objects and add data to them
        }
    }
```

Comment: fyi, class properties declared using `var` is version 4 and early 5. May I suggest that you look at more recent tutorials? The equivalent in version 5.3 and later is `public` instead of  `var`. It is perfectly valid PHP. It just declares everything as `public` which may not be the most useful thing to be doing with `object properties`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set properties directly to an instance of a custom class using MySQLi's `fetch_object()` method.  In your case, you might do it like this:

```
// It is best to not use SELECT * here
// You want to make sure the columns returned in result set
// match your class' properties names,
// so you may need to alias your columns here
$query = "
    SELECT `title`, `body`, `category`, `date`
    FROM `article`
    ORDER BY `date` DESC
    LIMIT 5";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    // create array to store your objects in
    $art_array = array();
    // specify the class name as first parameter to fetch_object()
    // you can also pass an array of parameters
    // to the class constructor in second parameter - not shown here
    while ($obj = $result->fetch_object('art')) {
        $art_array[] = $obj;   
    }
}
```

Note that the properties of the object instance are set BEFORE the constructor for the class is called when using `fetch_object()` in this manner. This is a little counter-intuitive and may require some re-thinking of the constructor logic if you know the class is going to be instantiated in this manner.

With regards to your last edit about sorting/limiting the number of objects returned, I would suggest you do this in your SQL using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` definitions.  It makes no sense to do this after the fact in PHP - for example think if you had 100 rows in the DB table - Why would you want to send all the information from the DB to the application, create 100 object instances in the application, etc. only to display 5 of them?  I have updated the SQL in my example to show this.

Please make sure that your column name or alias for the `date` property is escaped by backticks, as `date` is a reserved word in MySQL.  You may actually consider changing the name. More specific terminology such as `date_created`, `date_updated`, etc. is usually more useful than a more general term like `date` anyway.

Comment: Thank you so much, the way you explained it was easier to understand than the php documentation lol.